# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jpg')

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, I'm trying to pick a random anime from jikan, which will return an object containing a key images(an object). images containg a key jpg. It keeps saying that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jpg')". Please help! Thank you so much

This is the main component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./animedb.css";
import TopAnime from "./topanime";
import AnimeSearch from "./animesearch";
import AnimeRandom from "./animerandom";
import AnimeDisplay from "./animedisplay";
import NavBar from "./navbar";

const AnimeDB = () => {
  const [animeList, setAnimeList] = useState([]);
  const [isRandomAnime, setIsRandomAnime] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [topAnime, setTopAnime] = useState([]);
  const [searchAnime, setSearchAnime] = useState("");
  const [randomAnime, setRandomAnime] = useState({});
  const url = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3";

  const ShowAnime = async () => {
    let display_url = url + "/season/2022/spring";
    const response = await fetch(display_url);
    const result = await response.json();
    setAnimeList(result.anime.slice(0, 10));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    ShowAnime();
    FindTopAnime();
  }, []);

  const FindTopAnime = async () => {
    let top_url = url + "/top/anime/1/bypopularity";
    try {
      const res = await fetch(top_url);
      const result = await res.json();
      setTopAnime(result.top.slice(0, 5));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const FindSearchAnime = async (query) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=${query}&order_by=title&sort=asc`
      );
      const result = await res.json();
      setAnimeList(result.results.slice(0, 10));
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    FindSearchAnime(searchAnime);
  };

  const handleRandom = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setIsRandomAnime(true);
    let res = await fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v4/random/anime");
    let result = await res.json();
    setRandomAnime(result.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
    console.log(result.data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapperAnime">
      {/* <NavBar /> */}
      <h1 id="appName">
        u<strong id="strong">ME</strong>i
      </h1>
      <div className="container">
        <TopAnime topAnime={topAnime} />
        <div className="display">
          <button onClick={handleRandom}>Random Anime</button>
     
          <AnimeSearch
            onSearch={handleSearch}
            setSearchAnime={setSearchAnime}
            value={searchAnime}
          />
          <AnimeDisplay
            isLoading={isLoading}
            animeList={animeList}
            isRandomAnime={isRandomAnime}
            randomAnime={randomAnime}
            setIsRandomAnime={setIsRandomAnime}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AnimeDB;
```

component: AnimeDisplay:

```
function AnimeDisplay(props) {
  if (props.isRandomAnime) {
    let { mal_id, title, images } = props.randomAnime;
    return (
      <div className="collections">
        <div key={mal_id} className="card">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <img src={images.jpg.image_url} alt="test" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="collections">
        {props.animeList.map((ele) => {
          const { mal_id, image_url, title, episodes } = ele;
          if (props.isLoading) {
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
          }
          return (
            <div key={mal_id} className="card">
              <img src={image_url} alt="" />
              <h1>{title}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AnimeDisplay;
```

#Update: I've tried your ways, but it didn't work either. This is the returned data:

```
{mal_id: 43450, url: 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/43450/Shao_Nian_Effendi', images: {…}, trailer: {…}, title: 'Shao Nian Effendi', …}aired: {from: '2012-01-01T00:00:00+00:00', to: null, prop: {…}, string: '2012 to ?'}airing: falsebackground: nullbroadcast: {day: null, time: null, timezone: null, string: 'Unknown'}demographics: [{…}]duration: "12 min per ep"episodes: 104explicit_genres: []favorites: 0genres: []images: jpg: image_url: "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1248/118197.jpg"large_image_url: "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1248/118197l.jpg"small_image_url: "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1248/118197t.jpg"[[Prototype]]: Objectwebp: {image_url: 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1248/118197.webp', small_image_url: 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1248/118197t.webp', large_image_url: 'https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1248/118197l.webp'}[[Prototype]]: Objectlicensors: []mal_id: 43450members: 31popularity: 19210producers: []rank: 14029rating: "PG - Children"score: nullscored_by: nullseason: nullsource: "Other"status: "Finished Airing"studios: []synopsis: nullthemes: []title: "Shao Nian Effendi"title_english: nulltitle_japanese: "少年阿凡提"title_synonyms: (3) ['Shao Nian A Fan Ti', 'Shao Nian Afanti', 'Young Effendi']trailer: {youtube_id: null, url: null, embed_url: null, images: {…}}type: "TV"url: "https://myanimelist.net/anime/43450/Shao_Nian_Effendi"year: null[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your initial state doesn't have any "jpg" key and when it reads your code for the first time (before useEffect) it throws an error. you could either (the wrong way!) update your initial state like so: `useState([{images:{jpg:""}}])` or the right way which is conditional rendering!

Answer (score 0):

As [Shahryar_Jahanshahloo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12505723/shahryar-jahanshahloo) said, you must provide a default value for your initial state, so change the `randomAnime` this way:

```
// note that the object is much more greater than this, but I only included
// the properties that you are using

const [randomAnime, setRandomAnime] = useState({
  mal_id: "",
  title: "",
  images: { jpg: { image_url: "" } }
});
```

Another thing I notice that is wrong is your loading state in your `AnimeDisplay`, you should do something like this:

```
function AnimeDisplay(props) {
  const { mal_id, title, images } = props.randomAnime;
  
  // move the loading conditional to outside of the mapping
 // so when the component is fetching the data it only
// renders the loading element
  if (props.isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }
  
  // after the fetch you can render your components normally
  if (props.isRandomAnime) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="collections">
          <div key={mal_id} className="card">
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <img src={images?.jpg.image_url} alt="test" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="collections">
        {props.animeList.map((ele) => {
          const { mal_id, image_url, title, episodes } = ele;

          return (
            <div key={mal_id} className="card">
              <img src={image_url} alt="" />
              <h1>{title}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```